# Drop down input in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, drop-down-menu

How can I make the drop down show all the content of one option when it is expanded? If an option in the drop down is, for instance, a whole sentence and select tag width is small, the user in IE will not be able to read whole option. This is not the case in Mozilla where the whole content is shown when drop down is expanded.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior in IE8,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar constraint when working against IE8 and the oh so famous drop down list truncating. I have multiple drop down lists on my page, one after another, some inside top nav content, and IE8 decides to cut off my attribute option text properties. Now, like many of us, I don't want to set the width obscurely large, so this option is out of question.

After a lot of research, I couldn't find a great answer, so I went ahead and fixed it with jQuery and CSS:

First, let's make sure we are only passing our function in IE8:

```
    var isIE8 = $.browser.version.substring(0, 2) === "8.";
    if (isIE8) {
       //fix me code
    }
```

Then, to allow the select to expand outside of the content area, let's wrap our drop down lists in div's with the correct structure, if not already, and then call the helper function:

```
        var isIE8 = $.browser.version.substring(0, 2) === "8.";
    if (isIE8) {
        $('select').wrap('<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative; display: inline-block; float: left;"></div>').css('position', 'absolute');

        //helper function for fix
        ddlFix();
    }
```

Now onto the events. Since IE8 throws an event after focusing in for whatever reason, IE will close the widget after rendering when trying to expand. The work around will be to bind to **'focusin'** and **'focusout'** a class that will auto expand based on the longest option text. Then, to ensure a constant min-width that doesn't shrink past the default value, we can obtain the current select list width, and set it to the drop down list min-width property on the **'onchange'** binding:

```
    function ddlFix() {
    var minWidth;

    $('select')

    .each(function () {
        minWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).css('min-width', minWidth);
    })
    .bind('focusin', function () {
        $(this).addClass('expand');
    })
    .change(function () {
        $(this).css('width', minWidth);
    })
    .bind('focusout', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('expand');
    });
}
```

Lastly, make sure to add this class in the style sheet:

```
 select:focus, select.expand {
    width: auto;
}
```